# Using :Vexplore effectively

Tags: vim

So, the :Vexplore command in vim opens a nice little directory browser to the left.

But how do I then open a file from that side-pane into the main window on the right?

One would assume there's a simple mapping for it, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want `o` or `P`

Also, have a look at the documentation, e.g.

```
:he netrw-p11
```

Comment: <kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>P</kbd> works by splitting horizontally with opened file on Top. What does these 2 mean and is there a difference between these?

Comment: @hiru007 [netrw-o](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-o) opens a split, and [netrw-P](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-prvwin) opens in a previous window (last accessed). The docs has more specifics if you follow the links

Answer (score 9):

It turns out it's just a single line in .vimrc:

```
let g:netrw_browse_split=4      " Open file in previous buffer
```

Source: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/the-file-explorer/#comment-45366660

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure what you're looking for is this:

```
:Vexplore!
```

Comment: From what I can tell, adding the '!' makes the window appear on the right, instead of on the left, which is not at all what I was asking about.

Comment: Either way, since I asked this question, I've discovered the awesome Ctrl + P plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same command you would use to navigate to different windows in Vim (like quickfix window, or different split), everything is explained in

`:help windows.txt`

But to answer to your question directly:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to move to the left window
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>l</kbd> to move to the right window

then <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select the file you want to open.

You might want to read `:help netrw` as well

Comment: Thanks, I know how to navigate between windows. I was asking how to open a file in a different window than the one I'm currently in.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you question, I don't know the answer but it is probably explained in `:help netrw`

Answer (score 2):

The latest netrw plugin (up to v153f) now provides the :Lexplore command, which opens an explorer on the right hand side of the vim display.  It sets g:netrw_chgwin so edits occur in the window to the right of the netrw window.  You can get it from http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW .

Comment: Underrated comment, this just works in my vim on Slackware years later and is exactly the behavior I was looking for

Comment: Unfortunately it sets the ` g:netrw_chgwin` option *permanently* so subsequent :Explore will also open in files in new windows when you press `<CR>`